# How can object be null/undefined after checking that object property is an integer using Number.isInteger?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my code:

```
if (
  Number.isInteger(prevObj?.prop) &&
  Number.isInteger(nextObj?.prop) &&
  prevObj.prop !== nextObj.prop
) {
...
}
```

TypeScript is warning that `prevObj`/`nextObj` could be `null` or `undefined` ***after*** checking that `prop` is an integer.

If i use `typeof prevObj?.prop === 'number'` instead of `Number.isInteger`, the warnings go away.

Can you explain why TypeScript is showing these warnings?

Comment: If ```prevObj/nextObj``` can't be ```null``` or ```undefined``` why would you use ```?``` safe operator? use ```prevObj!.prop``` or ```nextObj!.prop``` and see what typescript says now

Comment: I don't think ts cares about `Number.isInteger` checks. It independently checks the expression `prevObj.prop !== nextObj.prop` for type errors (not 100% sure)

Comment: @JanatbekOrozaly `prevObj/nextObj` might be `null` or `undefined` in my case. But after confirming that a property within each object is a number, I expect that TS would know `prevObj/nextObj` are objects. If I use `typeof prevObj?.prop === 'number'` the error goes away. I think @adiga is right that TS ignores `Number.isInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is showing these warnings because the type checker doesn't know that prevObj and nextObj are defined when you use the optional chaining operator (?). When you use optional chaining, the type checker considers the type of the property to be a union of the actual type and undefined, so it doesn't know that the property is definitely an integer.

You can fix the issue by either using typeof to check the type of the property, as you mentioned, or by providing a type assertion to tell the type checker that the object is definitely defined:

```
    if (
          Number.isInteger((prevObj as { prop: number }).prop) &&
          Number.isInteger((nextObj as { prop: number }).prop) &&
          prevObj.prop !== nextObj.prop
        ) {
          // ...
    }
```

This will tell the type checker that prevObj and nextObj are definitely defined and have a property prop of type number, so it won't show the warning.